Proof when sets converge to the Cantor set and are decreasing, does this hold generally?
I have a question regarding a proof, first I will give the statement and the proof:

Define $C_0=[0,1]$, define
$C_n=\frac{C_{n-1}}{3}\cup(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{C_{n-1}}{3})$. Then
$C_{n+1}\subset C_{n}$.

Proof by induction:
It suffices to prove that if $x \in C_n$, then $\frac{x}{3}\in C_n$ and $\frac{2}{3}+\frac{x}{3}\in C_n$.
Base step:
It is easy to see that if $x \in [0,1]$ then $x/3\in [0,1]$ and $2/3+x/3 \in [0,1]$.
Inductive step
Assume that if $x \in C_n$, then $x/3 \in C_n$ and $2/3+x/3 \in C_n$.
Assume now that $y \in C_{n+1}$, then either $y=z/3, z \in C_n$ or $y =2/3+z/3, z \in C_n$. Because of the induction hypothesis it follows directly that $y\in C_n$.
But by construction of $C_{n+1}$ we must then have that $y/3$ and $2/3+y/3$ are in $C_{n+1}$.
$\square$
My question:
This proof seems to work. But what makes me wondering is the inductive step. It seems we are not really using $1/3$ and $2/3$, and that seems very strange. It seems that what should also work is:
If $C_{n+1}=\cup_{i=1}^K f_i(C_n)$ and $\cup_{i=1}^K f_i(C_0)\subset C_0$. Then $C_{n+1}\subset C_n$. But does this property hold? Can this proof be generalized?, because it doesn't seem to depend much on $1/3$ and $2/3$?
Or is it something about the Cantor set that makes it so simple?

Good idea!  This is a construction for any "iterated function system".

This is very general. Assume $F : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is a monotone function, i.e. $A \subseteq B$ implies $F(A) \subseteq F(B)$. Also fix $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(X) \subseteq X$. Then clearly
$$X \supseteq F(X) \supseteq F(F(X)) \supseteq \ldots,$$
i.e. $X_{n+1} \subseteq X_n$, where $X_n$ are defined by $X_0 := X$ and $X_{n+1} = F(X_n)$.
In the case of the Cantor set,
$$F(X) = \frac{1}{3} X \cup \left( \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{3} X \right)$$
is monotone and $F( [0, 1] ) \subseteq [0, 1]$. But other than that, there is nothing special about the specific numbers like $\frac{1}{3}$ here.
A special case of this generalization is as you suggest - when $F$ is given by a (finite) union of images via real functions, $F(X) = \bigcup_{i=1}^N f_i[X]$ for any $f_i : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $i = 1, \ldots, N$.

Thank you very much. It was really nice to get the clarification beween the set-functions and real functions. But just to clear up, you write finite in paranthesis, but it could be an infinite union, correct?

@user394334 Right, finiteness doesn't matter.
